# Laravel Realationship query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel4 on my project and I have those tables on Mysql Database ..

```
Users :
    - id  - username 
    1 - user1
    2 - user2
```

-

```
Blogs : 
    - id - blog_name
    1 - blog1
    2 - blog2
```

-

```
Roles :
    - id - role_name
    1- owner
    2- editor
```

-

```
Assigned_roles:
    - id - role_id - user_id - blog_id 
    1 - 1 - 1 - 1  // user1 owns blog1
    2 - 2 - 1 - 2  // user1 editor in blog2
```

In laravel, I can successfully deal with three tables using hasMany and BelognsToMany relationship .. but 4 tables! it was too complecated for me,

I have spent  2 days on this but I couldn't figur out how to achieve this in a simple way with one query or so.

What I'm trying to do is, When I login in to blog1 , I need to list all blogs that I have access on them , for example :

- blog (owner)
- blog2 (editor)

something like..

```
$user = User::find(1);
print_r($user->access_blogs); // list blogs that I have assigned roles to them
```

and maybe later ..

```
 $myrole = Blog::find(1)->where('user_id', 2);
 echo $myrole->myrole;  // editor
```

--

```
// 1
use LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent;
class User extends Ardent {

    public function blogs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Blog');
    }

}

// 2 
use LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent;
class Assignedroles extends Ardent {
    protected $table = 'assigned_roles';

}
```

.. etc , you got the idea .. :)

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot. Downside is, that it can't handle eager loading for the third table yet.

Comment: That looks interesting! I'm gonna check it out and see how could it help me with my issue here, Thanks a lot Jarek : )